How to change layer order or superimpose drawings
I was trying to do an animation of 2 characters on grease pencil. In my animation, the first character (bird) must pass in front of second (the hedgehog), but even if I change the order of the layers or put the bird in front of the hedgehog, in my camera, it appears behind.
I've already tried moving it in edit or object mode
How can I do this?


I've already tried moving it in edit and object mode but it still appears behind in my camera.

can u pls provide blend file so that we can see what's going on? thx.

yes it's here https://we.tl/t-47vbdmXuT0

Blender isn't a 2D drawing software, it's a 3D software with Grease Pencil (GP) objects in which you can draw. So you have both worlds' paradigms to play with:

Like in a 2D software, you can order layers within one GP object.
Like in a 3D software, you can move object or their content in the 3D space, either in object mode or in edit mode.

Though, using the 3D space seems to not work very well with GP objects that already have layers in them. So prefer having either one object with layers, or multiple objects with little to no layers. In your case,
If you prefer using layers
Select both objects in object mode, press ⎈ CtrlJ to join them into one object, and then order the GP layers as you want:

(Optionally spend some time renaming both objects' GP layers before joining the GP objects, so that you clearly know what each of them are.)
If you prefer using the 3D space:
Select your bird object, go to the Properties Editor > GP data tab, Strokes panel > Stroke Depth Order and change it to "3D location":


I've already tried moving it in edit and object mode but it still appears behind in my camera.

@mora Enabling the Z layer in the View Layer properties might help. It did for me, at least.

@mora Also, if your bird and hedgehog are in the same object, but in different layers, maybe try moving the bird's layer up above the hedgehog's layer.

@mora As in, in the properties panel for your grease pencil object, under the Object Data panel, select your layer, and push on the up arrow on the right side.

okay, thanks a lot, I'll try that :)

Sorry, my answer wasn't totally accurate, I made quite some changes. See the edit.
